# Heroku removed Mandrill add-on also removed config variables whose name having MANDRILL_ in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, mandrill

Heroku removed Mandrill add-on but they also removed config variables whose name having MANDRILL_ in it from our app. This impacted our code as we set those variables required. 
Why didn't Heroku just remove the add-on and leave the variables as is? How could we prevent this happen for other add-on in the future?

Comment: You're at the mercy of Heroku here. I'd contact their support department and find out if they have an answer.